# Update audio/wav blob FileField in Django via AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, blob

Having a real discouraging time trying to update a django field by saving a blob stored in JS variable via AJAX. Here's my view:

```
def update_audio(pk, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateAudio(data= request.POST, files= request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('valid form')
        else:
            print ('invalid form')
            print (form.errors)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

the url:

```
url(r'^update_audio/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)$', views.update_audio, name='update_audio'),
```

The form:

```
class UpdateAudio(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sounds

        fields = [
        'sound',
        ]
```

The form on the page:

```
<form id='update_audio' enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="">

        <input type="file" name="sound" id="id_sound" value=''>        

   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" onclick='upload()'/>
</form
```

> 

And the AJAX:

```
function upload(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
        var data = new FormData();
        data.set('sound', blob);



        function getCookie(name) {
            var cookieValue = null;
            if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
                var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
                for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                    var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                    // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                    if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cookieValue;
        }



        function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
            // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
            return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
        }
        $.ajaxSetup({
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            }
        });
        // debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'posts:update_audio' instance.pk %}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,   
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('success');
            }
        });
        return false;
        }

        $(function() {
            $('#update_audio').submit(upload);
        });
```

The blob is stored in the global var blob, which is being appended to the var data, which is a FormData instance. I'm getting a POST 403 Forbidden when trying to post. Any clues as to where I'm going wrong? Have been working on this for several days now and would really appreciate some pointers.
EDIT: was able to to pass the CSRF with the snippets suggested in the django docs [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/)

Comment: You need to add the csrf token to headers in the ajax request.

Comment: Thanks for the response, added the CSRF to the header (updated above) but still getting a 403 error.

Comment: Try this `$.ajaxSetup({ headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } })` . The forbidden 403 error is surely an indication that you are not sending csrf token .

Comment: Tried above but still to no success. Is there possibly something going on with the view ?Or is it even possible to upload an audio blob to a Django Filefield? Haven't been able to find a good example by googling so just a thought

Comment: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is missing from your `<form>` tag.

Comment: and where do you call your Ajax function?! Your `form action` calls `update_audio` which calls your view (also the view's name is in uppercase: `UpdateAudio`, typo maybe?). Call ajax function using `onclick="upload()"` event of form's button.

Comment: There's an event handler at the bottom of the ajax which triggers the function on form submit. I removed the action though, and tried triggering it with the onclick to be sure, but no luck. Still getting the 403, and I really think decimals' theory is correct, I'm just trying to exhaust the other possibilities. There must be some way to submit the token with the ajax header which Django will accept?

Comment: You are using url parameter pk for update_audio view but you don't take pk as parameter in your view. You need to add pk parameter to view function: def update_audio(request, pk):

Comment: Hey, that's what I was overlooking giaco! Thank you much. I also updated the CSRF token with some snippets in Django docs, which fixed the 403 (thanks decimal).  I'm able to get the success alert from the Ajax post, but very strangely the file remains the same (not updated with the new audio blob I tried to pass with the data). Is there something else I'm missing here? Do I possibly need to use an UpdateView?

Comment: Aren't you missing `form.save()` in your view?